# VS Code not recognizing variables while using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mean

Numpy is not working on VS Code
I tried using numpy on jupyter notebook. It worked over there.

```
import numpy s np
speed = [99, 54, 68, 90]
x = np.mean(speed)
print(x)
```

I am getting error that x is not defined.
I retried downloading numpy

Comment: is it a typo that it isn't ```import numpy as np```?

Comment: Did you check python version and numpy library on VSCode?

Comment: `import numpy s np` this does give you an error?